# Gambler's ruin: $\mathbb{P}\left\{ X_\tau=n \mid X_1 = k+1\right\}=\mathbb{P}\left\{ X_\tau = n\mid X_0 = k+1\right\}\,?$

Tags: probability, markov-chains

[image]

I don't understand the last part. How do we get $p_{k+1}$ and $p_{k-1}$? I understand it intuitively but I'm have trouble writing things down. It seems like we define $\tau$ as

$$\tau :=\min\left\{t\ge 0:X_t=0\text{ or } X_t = n\right\}$$

And I think $p_k$ is

$$\mathbb{P}\left\{X_\tau=n \mid X_0=k \right\}$$

Let $\Delta_i$'s be Bernoulli with $p=0.5$. I have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left\{ X_\tau = n\mid X_0=k\right\}&= \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}\left\{ X_\tau=n \mid X_1 = k+1\right\} +\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}\left\{ X_\tau=n \mid X_1 = k-1\right\}
\end{align*}

But not the quesiton is, why is it true that

$$\mathbb{P}\left\{ X_\tau=n \mid X_1 = k+1\right\}=\mathbb{P}\left\{ X_\tau = n\mid X_0 = k+1\right\}\,?$$

Comment: What exactly id not clear? the derivation of the recurrence?

Comment: "is exactly $p_{k+1}$", I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: This is Markov's property.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Markov property doesn't suggest $P( A \mid X_0=x) = P(A \mid X_1=x)$, right?

Comment: You may want to see [Theorem 1.3.2](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s13.pdf) for Norris's *Markov Chains*.

Comment: @3x89g2 have you clarified your doubts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that at a certain step $p_k$, by definition, represent the probability that the gambler reach fortune $n$ with $k$ dollars, thus since at the next step we have only two possibilities:

- the gambler win and earns $k+1$ dollars
- or the gambler loose and earns $k-1$ dollars

for the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) we have

$$p_k=\frac12 p_{k-1}+\frac12 p_{k+1}$$

Comment: So at step $t=0$ and $t=1$, $p_k$ should be different and it depends on $t$?

Comment: we don't know what $p_k$ is but we know that exists (as a function of the dollars earned by the gambler and n) and that it have to satisfy the recurrence equation for the law of total probability, by standard method we can then obtain the esplicit relation for $p_k$

Comment: @3x89g2 take also a look here to the lecture by Joe Blitzstein, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNrqCdslGi4